# Is there an AI technique (or general programming technique) suitable for seeing if two articles deal with the same event?

Tags: comparison, classification

I'm looking for a way to work out if two or more articles deal with the same event or issue and I'm not sure where to start.

For example, back in August 2022 there were a few articles on the latest developments in AlphaFold, such as:

Nature: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-022-02088-x
The Economist: https://www.economist.com/alphafold-pod
Chemistry World: https://www.chemistryworld.com/opinion/why-alphafold-wont-revolutionise-drug-discovery/4016051.article

If I'm downloading hundreds or thousands of articles, what's the best way to pick out those three articles and work out that they're dealing with the same piece of new news? I imagine there must be a way given Google News groups similar news items together, but I'm not sure how difficult it would be.

Any guidance or directions would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: There is one rather simple way to classify articles based on relevance if you use publication date and article title as the input to a supervised model. To learn more fine-grained distinctions, check out the event-dataset:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352340919304019#fig1.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll check that out.